# Nginx how to completly disable Proxy caching

Tags: caching, nginx

For what i understand [proxy_cache](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpProxyModule#proxy_cache) can only be disable by changing the incoming request headers to somtehing like Cache-Control': 'no-cache'. This seems to not be working for me, is there any way to completly disble caching for that proxy ?

proxy_cache off didn t work either response headers always come back like that:

> Cache-Control max-age=86400
>
> Connection    keep-alive
>
> Content-Type  text/plain
>
> Date  Mon, 19 Mar 2012 19:42:28 GMT
>
> Expires   Tue, 20 Mar 2012 19:42:28 GMT
>
> Server    nginx/0.7.65
>
> Transfer-Encoding chunked

Aldo the request i am proxing are comming from node.js server so i need to enable "streaming"

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just needed to set `expires off;` within my proxy location block..